# Efficiently convert IQueryable<TSource> to ImmutableArray<TSource> using the async and await pattern in one step

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to *select* a *collection* into an *immutable array* in the most efficient way possible.

I'm also want to make it clear the intent of the result set as *readonly* / *immutable* / *not tracked*.

```
var someCollection = await _dataContext
    .Set<someType>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

I can do this then convert to *immutable* but that seems crazy.

```
var someImmutableCollection = someCollection
    .ToImmutableArray();
```

I can also just do this:

```
var someCollection = _dataContext
    .Set<someType>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToImmutableArray();
```

But this is not `async`.

Is there a reason why there is no `ToImmutableArrayAsync()`?

Or is there a better way using `async` to get an immutable array from efcore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I can do this then convert to immutable but that seems crazy.
>
> ```
> var someImmutableCollection = someCollection
>     .ToImmutableArray();
> ```

Crazy? Not so much. Let's have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/b970bf29a46521f40862a01db9e276e6448d3cb0/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2361)

```
public static async Task<TSource[]> ToArrayAsync<TSource>(
     [NotNull] this IQueryable<TSource> source,
     CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
       => (await source.ToListAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
           .ToArray(); // anti-climax
```

Well, not much magic happening there.

Just create your own *extension*

```
public class MySuperExtensions
{   
    public static async Task<ImmutableArray<TSource>> ToImmutableArrayAsync<TSource>(
         [NotNull] this IQueryable<TSource> source,
         CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
           => (await source.ToListAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
               .ToImmutableArray(); // yehaa
}
```

Crisis averted, problem solved.

---

Or more efficiently, saving an extra allocation and an `IAsyncStateMachine` Implementation

```
public static async Task<ImmutableArray<TSource>> ToImmutableArrayAsync<TSource>(
   [NotNull] this IQueryable<TSource> source,
   CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
   var builder = ImmutableArray.CreateBuilder<TSource>();
   await foreach (var element in source.AsAsyncEnumerable().WithCancellation(cancellationToken))
       builder.Add(element);

   return builder.ToImmutable();
}
```

Comment: O wow haha I didn't know it did that under that hood. Thats a fair response. Is there a reason as to why ToArrayAsync is implemented in that way. Is it because the length of the collection is not known until the source is enumerated perhaps.

Comment: @Spaceman short answer yes. I have also added a more efficient incarnation that saves an allocation